# Why i got the output as "\"userName\"" and not like that "userName"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rest, expo

Why i got output `"\"userName\""` and not as `"userName"` ?
in my example i try to do an get api that attach to it some data and that data comes from the async-storage.
when i console the output so its shows the data like that :

```
"\"userName\""
```

but it should output `"userName"` .
what is the way to fix that issue ?

so what is wrong in my way ?

```
const getSaveUserTokenData = async (data) => {
    const url =
      'https://URL/userName,userToken,PlatformType,DeviceID?' +
      'userName=' +
      data.userName +
      '&userToken=' +
      data.googlToken +
      '&PlatformType=' +
      data.platformId +
      '&DeviceID=' +
      data.deviceId;
    await fetch(
      url,

      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: data.azureToken,
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: What is the issue? This should work, in theory. Assuming the URL you generate is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this way as well:

```js
fetchFunction = async () => {

    let data = {
        userName: 'jon',
        userToken: 'bee22',
        PlatformType: 'os-ios',
        DeviceID: '222222'
    }


    const url = `https://yoururl.com/?userName=${encodeURIComponent(data.userName)}&userToken=${encodeURIComponent(data.userToken)}&PlatformType=${encodeURIComponent(data.PlatformType)}&DeviceID=${encodeURIComponent(data.DeviceID)}`;


    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    const json = await response.json();

    console.log(json);

}
```

Comment: can u show me please how i do ur example with my code?

Comment: Would you like to pass these data to your server?

Comment: @shira, Updated my answer. Please have a look at this.

Comment: i need to put also header..can u see my update above ?please  try to fix my example into the right why .

Comment: @shira, you can pass the header like this which I've added to my answer.

Comment: can u help me with my new issue above please coz i dont understand why its happen.

Comment: @shira, what is happening? And change your URL by my answer's url.

Comment: my example above works but when i print the data it gives me in console :
"\"username\"" , "\"UserToken\"" ...and i want it will be "username" , "UserToken"

Comment: Just use `JSON.stringify("your_data")` to see data in json format.

Comment: When you get the response and print the data with **`console.log('Success:', data);`** this line, just print it through **`console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(data))`** and see how the output comes.

Comment: can u help me with this question please ? 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752575/react-native-there-is-way-to-identify-a-device-type-smartphone-tablet-lapto)

Answer (score 1):

If your variable names are the one you want in your url, try this:

```js
const getData = async () => {
    let userName = 'jon';
    let userToken = 'bee22';
    let PlatformType = 'os-ios';
    let DeviceID = '222222';

    const queryString = Object.entries({
      userName,
      userToken,
      PlatformType,
      DeviceID,
    })
      .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
      .join('&');

    
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://url...?' + queryString
    );
  };
};
```

Note: user token should not be in the url but usually in the headers of your request, like so:

```
fetch(someUrl, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: userToken
  }
});
```

Comment: do u know how to use SQLite ?

Comment: @shira please stop sending notifications that are not relevant to this particular question. Ask a new question with the SQLite tag and you will find relevant contributors that might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch(`https://yoururl.com/${userName}`,
        { method: 'GET',
          headers: myHeaders,
          mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'default' 
})
.then(function(response) {
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: can u show me please how i do ur example with my code?

Comment: Welocome to stackoverflow. Can you provide more explanation? You are answering a difficult question as it is difficult to test. Why do you think the OP code does not work and why your code would?

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution would be something like this:

```js
async function get(route, ...params) {
  const url = `${route}${params.map(p => `/${p}`)}`;
  const response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers });
  if (!response.ok)
    throw new Error(`Http error status: ${response.status}`);

  return response.json();
}
```

by using `...params` you can pass a generic amount of parameters that will then be combined with:

```js
 const url = `${route}${params.map(p => `/${p}`)}`;
```

In your case you would call the method like this:

```js
const result = await get("https://url..", "jon", "bee22", "os-ios", "222222");
```