# REACT NATIVE : There is way to identify a device type (smartphone, tablet, laptop)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, expo

There is way to identify a device type (smartphone, tablet, laptop) ?
I need to  identify a device type as:  smartphone, tablet, laptop ..
i try to use the **"react-native-device-info"** api library but dont understand how to identify the 3 specific devices type (smartphone, tablet, laptop) .

So how can i do some code that will gives me if its "Handset"=> Smartphone , if its "unknown"=> Laptop/Computer and it will be saved as well in my async-storage.

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

// how can i do some code that will gives me if its "Handset"=> Smartphone , 
//if its "unknown"=> Laptop/Computer 
//and it will be saved as well in my async-storage.

//this some example that i wanna get it works well coz now its not work good

const funct1=  (type) => {
let type = DeviceInfo.getDeviceType();

if type==='Handset'{
  AsyncStorage.setItem('PLATFORM-TYPE', 'Smartphone');
}
if type==='unknown'{
  AsyncStorage.setItem('PLATFORM-TYPE', 'Laptop/Computer');
}
};
```

Comment: Have you solved this, yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [API DOC](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#api) you can use these APIs to detect the device types:

- [getDeviceType](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getDeviceType)
- [isTablet](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#istablet)
- [isEmulator](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#isemulator)
- [getModel](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getmodel)

There are so many APIs to get the device name or any other use-cases. Read the API doc :) Also you cannot detect the `laptop` as far as I know, React Native does not for on PC.

Answer (score 5):

In the mentioned `react-native-device-info` there is a method `getDeviceType()` that returns

- `Handset` for smartphones,
- `Tablet` for tablets,
- `Tv` for TV and
- `unknown` for everything else (most probably it would be laptops)

Comment: like this answer

Comment: @shira and what is not working in your code? If you don't know what is in DeviceInfo.getDeviceType(), you can just use `console.log(DeviceInfo.getDeviceType())` to fetch device type and then try to manually test your code

Comment: do u know how to use SQLite ?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I am using expo, How can I find is device is `tablet` or `handset`

Comment: You need ejecting to use `react-native-device-info`